# Popen subprocess Named Window

Tags: python, popen

This is the Popen code I'm using to open a subprocess (file subprocessShortLaunch.py) in a separate terminal. I've been looking around and I can't find the answer to two questions:

1. Is there a way to 'name' the terminal window that opens? The terminal window just says 'terminal'.
2. Is there a way to keep the window open once the process has finished? It seems to automatically close if there is an error of some type.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
        "gnome-terminal -x python ~/Desktop/subprocessShortLaunch.py", 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=None,
        shell=True
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

## name the window

(1.) You're using `gnome-terminal`.
If you choose [`xterm`](https://www.mankier.com/1/xterm) instead,
you could supply a `-title foo` argument.

(2.) X11 applications support X properties,
manipulated by utilities like `xprop`.
You can set such properties,
external to gnome-terminal.
In the -title section xterm's man page explains that

> X Toolkit sets the WM_NAME property using this value.

(3.) Terminal emulators usually support ANSI
escape codes that were used by DEC's VT-100
terminals. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#OSC_(Operating_System_Command)_sequences) explains this:

> Xterm allows the window title to be set by `ESC ]0;your favorite window title`.

I imagine that gnome also supports ANSI escapes.
Try it and see.
It's just a matter of adding a `print()`
to your script.

## remain open

> Is there a way ... ?

Yes, there are many ways,
such as trapping errors and having
an error handler pause so the diagnostics
can be read.

Here is the simplest approach.

You are running `subprocessShortLaunch.py`.
Create a very short `launch.sh` script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

cd ~/Desktop
python ./subprocessShortLaunch.py
echo Please type RETURN
read line
```

Invoke with

```
gnome-terminal -x bash ~/Desktop/launch.py
```

So the Bourne shell will run
the (buggy) python script,
explain that the party's over,
and wait for you to depress the ENTER key.
That gives you time to view any
diagnostic output before you
dismiss the window.
A `sleep` statement could
be used for similar effect.

Comment: So instead of "gnome-terminal -x python ~/Desktop/subprocessShortLaunch.py",  it would be "gnome-terminal -x python ~/Desktop/launch.sh" ??

Comment: No. When I said "Bourne shell" I was referring to the `bash` shebang line. Commands like `echo` and `read` are bash commands, not python commands. I am proposing that a launch.sh wrapper script would be a "nanny" for the other script. We _could_ write such a wrapper in python, it would just be a bit longer. Oh BTW use `cd` or adjust `$PATH` or hardcode that Desktop folder if script is not in current directory.

Comment: Then I don't understand how to launch the script. I get that launch.sh would open the subprocessShortLaunch.py --- aka be the nanny for the python script. But I don't know how to call it, or run Launch.sh, if not from the gnome-terminal line?

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I added an "invoke with ..." line.